# ArrayList<Date> how to count the number of occurrences by Month/Year

Tags: java, date, jsp, arraylist

Im having some trouble to get out of this problem by my own.
Basically I`m working whit a ArrayList with 4.611 registers of Dates.
Those Dates are between the year of 2018 and 2020, and their format is "yyyy-MM-dd HH:SS"

Here is my code where I could pass the String data into Date. So for so good.

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
                ArrayList<Date> dataUser = new ArrayList<Date>();

                User user;
                for (int i = 0; i < listaUser.size(); i++) {
                    user = (User) listaUser.get(i);
                    if (user != null) {
                        Date dataLead = formatter.parse(user.getCREATED_AT());
                        dataUser.add(dataLead);
                    }
                
                }
```

My problem is that I need to know how many dates ares included in every Year and every Month.
For example;
2020-01-01
2020-01-03
2020-01-05
2020-04-01
2020-04-02
2020=04-29
2018-01-01
2018-01-04

The return must be:
3 for 2020-01 (January/2020)
3 for 2020-04 (April/2020)
2 for 2018-01 (January/2018)

Is there any way to do this? I`ve tried all kind of for loops but no success...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## *java.time*

You are using terrible date-time classes that were supplanted years ago by the *java.time* classes. Never use `java.util.Date`.

### `LocalDateTime`

Use `LocalDateTime` class to represent your input values, a date with a time-of-day but without a time zone.

```
ArrayList< LocalDateTime > dataUser = …
```

Your input strings are close to the standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats used by default in *java.time*. Just replace the SPACE in the middle with a `T` to comply with the standard.

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( input.replace( " " , "T" ) ;
```

Example code:

```java
List < String > inputs = List.of( "2020-01-01 13:00:00" , "2020-01-03 11:00:00" , "2020-01-05 17:00:00" , "2020-04-01 01:00:00" ,
        "2020-04-02 19:00:00" , "2020-04-29 23:00:00" , "2018-01-01 14:00:00" , "2018-01-04 05:00:00" );
System.out.println( "inputs = " + inputs );

List < LocalDateTime > ldts = new ArrayList <>( inputs.size() );
for ( String input : inputs )
{
    try
    {
        LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( input.replace( " " , "T" ) );
        Objects.requireNonNull( ldt );
        ldts.add( ldt );
    }
    catch ( Exception e )
    {
        // Faulty input.
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
System.out.println( "ldts = " + ldts );
```

When run.

```
inputs = [2020-01-01 13:00:00, 2020-01-03 11:00:00, 2020-01-05 17:00:00, 2020-04-01 01:00:00, 2020-04-02 19:00:00, 2020-04-29 23:00:00, 2018-01-01 14:00:00, 2018-01-04 05:00:00]
ldts = [2020-01-01T13:00, 2020-01-03T11:00, 2020-01-05T17:00, 2020-04-01T01:00, 2020-04-02T19:00, 2020-04-29T23:00, 2018-01-01T14:00, 2018-01-04T05:00]
```

### `YearMonth`

From those `LocalDate` objects, get a `YearMonth` object that represents, well, the year and the month only, without the day-of-month.

```
YearMonth yearMonth = YearMonth.from( ldt ) ;
```

### Group by year-month

Create a `Map< YearMonth , List< LocalDate > >` to segregate the date objects by year-month. Then interrogate the list for its size to get your desired count.

```java
Map < YearMonth, List < LocalDateTime > > mapYearMonthToLdts = new TreeMap <>();
```

Loop through all your `LocalDateTime`, determine each one’s year-month. Look in the map to see if there is a list already assigned for that year-month. If not yet assigned a list, make a list, and assign it to the map. Lastly, add the `LocalDateTime` object to that list whether pre-existing or newly created.

```java
for ( LocalDateTime ldt : ldts )
{
    List < LocalDateTime > listOfLdts = mapYearMonthToLdts.get( YearMonth.from( ldt ) );
    if ( listOfLdts == null )
    {
        listOfLdts = new ArrayList <>();
        mapYearMonthToLdts.put( YearMonth.from( ldt ) , listOfLdts );
    }
    listOfLdts.add( ldt );
}
System.out.println( "mapYearMonthToLdts = " + mapYearMonthToLdts );
```

When run.

```
mapYearMonthToLdts = {2018-01=[2018-01-01T14:00, 2018-01-04T05:00], 2020-01=[2020-01-01T13:00, 2020-01-03T11:00, 2020-01-05T17:00], 2020-04=[2020-04-01T01:00, 2020-04-02T19:00, 2020-04-29T23:00]}
```

#### Multimap

The map-related code above is old-school. Modern Java makes this much simpler.

Our map is actually a [*multimap*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multimap), where the key leads to a collection of values rather than a single value. Modern Java provides multimap syntax via [`Map::computeIfAbsent`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#computeIfAbsent(K,java.util.function.Function)) method added to Java 8 and later.

```java
for ( LocalDateTime ldt : ldts )
{
    mapYearMonthToLdts
            .computeIfAbsent( YearMonth.from( ldt ) , ( x -> new ArrayList <>() ) )  // Retrieves the value (a list) matching the key, after creating one if none found to be pre-existing.
            .add( ldt );  // Add this value to the retrieved/created list.
}
System.out.println( "mapYearMonthToLdts = " + mapYearMonthToLdts );
```

Output remains the same. This new-school code is not better, just shorter, and easier to comprehend when reviewing code later. If you are not yet comfortable with lambda syntax, use the old-school code seen earlier.

### Report results

You wanted a count of elements per year-month.

We can build a report by looping the keys, looping the `YearMonth` objects. For each year-month key, we retrieve its `List` of `LocalDateTime`. We interrogate that list for its size.

```java
for ( YearMonth yearMonth : mapYearMonthToLdts.keySet() )
{
    System.out.println( "yearMonth = " + yearMonth + " has a count of: " + mapYearMonthToLdts.get( yearMonth ).size() );
}
```

When run.

```
yearMonth = 2018-01 has a count of: 2
yearMonth = 2020-01 has a count of: 3
yearMonth = 2020-04 has a count of: 3
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes. Hibernate 5 & JPA 2.2 support *java.time*.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - [**Java 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) brought some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android (26+) bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), a process known as [*API desugaring*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#library-desugaring) brings a [subset of the *java.time*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) functionality not originally built into Android.

    - If the desugaring does not offer what you need, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above) to Android. See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Comment: Thank you very much Sir!

Answer (score 3):

> Those Dates are between the year of 2018 and 2020, and their format is "yyyy-MM-dd HH:SS"

Nope. Not possible.

Date is lying to you. A bald-faced lie at that. a Date **does not** represent a date. Weird, huh?

It represents a moment in time. Like, when the sun had that flare, that kind of 'moment in time'.

The problem is, when that sun had the big flareup? It was october in russia but november in most of the rest of the world. It was the 30th in america and the 31st in europe. Etcetera.

**It is not possible to turn a j.u.Date into a month and day-of-month**. Not without providing a timezone.

### The proper solution

Don't use Date; it is an obsolete type, and most of its methods (such as `.getYear()` are deprecated, with a warning they they are broken. The proper types to use for date and time stuff are all in the `java.time` package. This package also contains ways to parse things; you should parse your stuff in yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm format into a `java.time.LocalDateTime` object, which doesn't lie - that really does represent a date and a time, and a 'local' one (so no timezone information provided at all), which is exactly what you have.

LDTs have `getYear()` and `getMonth() methods which return sane values (vs. Calendar which has those, but they return insane values, so you don't want java.util.Calendar either. That is also obsolete API).

Once you have a `List<LocalDateTime>` this becomes easy, and it won't get messed up due to timezone settings, as this code is timezone free:

```
var pattern = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm", Locale.ENGLISH);

Map<String, List<LocalDateTime>> result =
  listaUser.stream()
  .map(a -> (User) a)
  .map(User::getCREATED_AT)
  .map(a -> LocalDateTime.parse(a, pattern))
  .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
    a -> String.format("%4d-%2d", a.getYear(), a.getMonth())));
```

now your `result` map contains, for example, as key "2020-01" and the associated value is a list with all of the dates in your input with that year/month combo. If all you want is how many there are, .size() on that will tell you.

Answer (score 1):

Add new method which will find occurrence of year + month like following

```
private void getCountOfDate(String date,Map<String,Integer> countMap){
        String dateStr = date.substring(0,date.lastIndexOf("-"));
        if(countMap.containsKey(dateStr)){
            countMap.put(dateStr, countMap.get(dateStr)+1);
        }else{
            countMap.put(dateStr, 1);
        }
     
     }
```

Call this method from within your code

```
            User user;
            Map<String,Integer> user.getCREATED_AT()= new HashMap<>();
            for (int i = 0; i < listaUser.size(); i++) {
                user = (User) listaUser.get(i);
                if (user != null) {
                    Date dataLead = formatter.parse(user.getCREATED_AT());
                    dataUser.add(dataLead);
                    getCountOfDate(user.getCREATED_AT(),user.getCREATED_AT())
                }
            
            }
```

Now iterate the map for keys and get your values.

Comment: For now on im not saying Thank God anymore. Im saying Thank Gurpreet.

Answer (score 1):

### java.time and a stream operation

Using java.time, the modern Java date and time API, and a stream with the right combination of collectors, this doesn’t take a lot:

```
    List<LocalDate> dataUser = List.of(
            LocalDate.of(2018, Month.JANUARY, 3),
            LocalDate.of(2020, Month.NOVEMBER, 26),
            LocalDate.of(2018, Month.JANUARY, 18),
            LocalDate.of(2019, Month.SEPTEMBER, 12));
    
    Map<YearMonth, Long> countsPerMonth = dataUser.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(YearMonth::from, Collectors.counting()));
    
    countsPerMonth.forEach((ym, n) -> System.out.println("" + ym + ": " + n + " occurrense/s"));
```

Output from this example is:

> ```
> 2018-01: 2 occurrense/s
> 2019-09: 1 occurrense/s
> 2020-11: 1 occurrense/s
> ```

### Link

[Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.